# Transfer n number of rows with n number of columns into a single column | python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, transpose

I have 100 rows and 10 000 columns in a CSV format. I need to transfer all rows (100 per column, while there is 10 000 columns) into one single column, meaning the total number of columns at the end would be 1 million. Data type is consisted of float values. I tried various ways using transpose, but I could not find a proper solution.

Basically I would need something like this:

```
      A      B      C
 0  10.83  10.74  11.53
 1  13.45  12.74  11.78
 2  14.38  10.11  17.16
```

to convert into this:

```
      A
 0  10.83
 1  10.74
 2  11.53
 3  13.45
 4  12.74
 5  11.78
 6  14.38
 7  10.11
 8  17.16
```

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: "...into **one** single column, meaning the **total number of columns** at the end would be **1 000 000**." - so how many - **one** or **1 million** columns?

Comment: @MarianD it would be 1 million. I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: 1 million columns, or 1 million rows?

Comment: @MarianD 1 million columns. I have values in 100 of rows, and all rows have 10 thousand columns. When each row is transferred into a column, the total number of columns would be 100 x 10000 = 1 million.

Comment: So you have edit your question, particularly replace "...into one single **column**..." to "...into one single **row**..." (columns are vertical, rows are horizontal). On the other hand, your example shows that you wanted **1 column** with 1 million elements (rows).

Comment: @MarianD I need a all rows from all columns into a single column, not a single row. Anyway, `@anky_91 answered my question. Thanks mate.

Comment: You don't understand me. No, robmiller505 didn't solve your problem, **anky_91** solved it in the first comment to your answer 1 hour ago. robmiller505's answer is a **duplicate of it**, moreover not correct, with error in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anky_91 suggested, following function solved the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)drop=True)
```

Comment: It means, anky_91 deserves points for it, not you. Moreover, your answer is not correct.